# How to change Text size of TexView's within a LinearLayout while dragging on it

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a linear layout which contains number of TextView's. Each text view changes its Text Size if we touch on it.

I want to do that if I touch on First one and keep dragging within linear layout without pulling my finger up. TextView which has my finger on should change its size and if i drag away from that textView its size should come to normal so on.

I have MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView firstText, secondText;
        firstText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
        secondText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondTextView);

        firstText.setOnTouchListener(this);
        secondText.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ) {

        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(40);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(20);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

xml is:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="0.9" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please help. I want the behaviour if I touch on firstTextView its size i grown and move my finger towards secondTextView when finger is out of the bounds of firstTextView its text size is become normal and without pulling off my finger i keep on moving towards secondTextView and whenever my finger enters in bounds of secondTextView its size is changed.

the problem is when finger enters on secondTextView it doesn't take effect.

Comment: Any tutorial would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use setonTouchListener method for TextView.

Comment: I think that this tutorial would be helpful http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/

Comment: @Piyush Please see my edit for further clarification.

Comment: @Ahmed bhai I dont want to displace my TextView's I just need to highlight Text of TextViews on drag event within a linear layout. Please see my edit for the code. thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can call setOnTouchListener on your textView. Then depending on how you want the size to grow either record the time of the touch or the distance moved using the fields on the passed in touch event to change the size of the text view.